# $f'(x)=0 ,\forall x>0$ and $f'(x)=1 , \forall x \le 0$

Tags: real-analysis

Does there exist a function on the set of real numbers such that $f'(x)=0 ,\forall x>0$ and $f'(x)=1 , \forall x \le 0$ ?

Comment: $f'(x)=1$ implies $f(x)=??$ ....$f'(x)=0$ implies $f(x)=??$

Comment: Consider $f(x)=\min(x,0)$

Comment: @Lion, but this is not differentiable at $x=0$, so it fails to satisfy the conditions.

Answer (score 8):

Using Darboux's Theorem according to which the derivative of any function satisfies the intermediate value property, no such function can exist.

This is however an overkill since if such an $f$ existed, then it is constant for $x>0$, i.e., $f(x)=d$, and is of the form $f(x)=x+c$ for $x<0$. For the derivative to exist at $x=0$ the function must be continuous there, which implies that $c=d$. But such a function is not differentiable at $x=0$ as can be verified directly from the definition.

Comment: it should be: "For the derivative to exist at $x = 0$"

Answer (score 0):

Such a function will never exists because the Darboux's theorem states that the derivative of a function which is defined on an interval has the intermediate value property.